# How can I directly save a file to Google Cloud using Java APIs and without initializing it locally?

Tags: java, api, file, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to figure out how can I save this file(.flac) directly to google cloud without initializing it locally. Is it possible actually? I have all the needed dependencies, libraries, etc. Thanks in advance!

```
public static void saveAudio() {
        try {
            byte[] audio = Record.out.toByteArray();
            InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(audio);

            final AudioFormat format = getFormat();

            final AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(input, format, audio.length / format.getFrameSize());

            File file = new File(FILE_PATH_TO_SAVE);
            AudioSystem.write(ais, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, file);

            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);

            final SourceDataLine line = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

            line.open(format);
            line.start();

            Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
                final int bufferSize = (int) format.getSampleRate() * format.getFrameSize();
                final byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                public void run() {
                    try {
                        int count;
                        while ((count = ais.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                            if (count > 0) {
                                line.write(buffer, 0, count);
                            }
                        }

                        line.drain();
                        line.close();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.err.println("I/O problems: " + e);
                        System.exit(-3);
                    }
                }
            };

            Thread playThread = new Thread(runner);
            playThread.start();
            cloudSave();

        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            System.err.println("Line unavailable: " + e);
            System.exit(-4);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

I've tried to do it with the information provided in google docs but I didn't manage to find a solution. I just know that we have to use Storage, Bucket, BlobId, BlobInfo, Blob, and stuff like that. But I'm not quite sure about the implementation so I'm asking here!

Comment: what's the `cloudSave();` thing about?

Comment: @eduyayo, I'm sorry for not mentioning it. That's a custom method doing nothing basically.

Comment: you've got code here for the upload https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-stream-file-upload?hl=es-419 ... BTW... you need a developer account and *initialize the client* before running it